how to point to sun and moon in cesiumjs?
CesiumJS does properly simulatr both Sun and Moon positions in realtime, but for some reasons they are apparently not directly accessible: Moon object is just an ellipsoid, placed "somewhere".

How to know the cartesian coordinates of this somewhere?
How to look at this point?
How to draw a line from observer to this point?

I tested several sources from stackoverflow and cesium community, but they all sparse, approximate, buggy...
I even found an undocumented lookAtMoon() function in MoonSpec.js file, but I can't figure out how to access it!
function lookAtMoon(camera, date) {
  const icrfToFixed = new Matrix3();
  if (!defined(Transforms.computeIcrfToFixedMatrix(date, icrfToFixed))) {
    Transforms.computeTemeToPseudoFixedMatrix(date, icrfToFixed);
  }

  const moonPosition = Simon1994PlanetaryPositions.computeMoonPositionInEarthInertialFrame(
    date
  );
  Matrix3.multiplyByVector(icrfToFixed, moonPosition, moonPosition);

  camera.viewBoundingSphere(
    new BoundingSphere(moonPosition, Ellipsoid.MOON.maximumRadius)
  );
}


I found that internal functions which calculate Moon and Sun position (Simon1994PlanetaryPositions)  return results in ICRF (International Celestial Reference Frame), which gives incorrect results if directly used to rotate camera or draw lines: you need to convert in advance to  Earth-Fixed frame axes (ITRF); this is done by specifying the time of the conversion and using it to create a transformation matrix to be applied to raw results:
function getMoonSunPos() {
      var icrfToFixed = new Cesium.Matrix3(); // Prepare conversion matrix
      Cesium.Transforms.computeTemeToPseudoFixedMatrix(viewer3D.clock.currentTime, icrfToFixed); // Convert from ICRF reference to Fixed reference
      var moonPos = Cesium.Simon1994PlanetaryPositions.computeMoonPositionInEarthInertialFrame(viewer3D.clock.currentTime); // Calculate  moon position: result is in ICRF
      Cesium.Matrix3.multiplyByVector(icrfToFixed, moonPos, moonPos); // Convert moon position from ICRF to  Fixed

      Cesium.Transforms.computeTemeToPseudoFixedMatrix(viewer3D.clock.currentTime, icrfToFixed);
      var sunPos = Cesium.Simon1994PlanetaryPositions.computeSunPositionInEarthInertialFrame(viewer3D.clock.currentTime);
      Cesium.Matrix3.multiplyByVector(icrfToFixed,sunPos,sunPos);

      return {moon : moonPos, sun : sunPos};
    }

Once you get the right positions, you can use them to calculate Altitude and Azimuth:
function getHeading(pointA,pointB){
    const transform=Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(pointA);
    const positionvector=Cesium.Cartesian3.subtract(pointB,pointA,new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    const vector=Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPointAsVector(Cesium.Matrix4.inverse(transform,new Cesium.Matrix4()),positionvector,new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    const direction=Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(vector,new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    //heading
    var headingTemp=Math.atan2(direction.y,direction.x)-Cesium.Math.PI_OVER_TWO;
    var heading =parseFloat(  ((Cesium.Math.TWO_PI-Cesium.Math.zeroToTwoPi(headingTemp))*180/Math.PI).toFixed(2));
  
    //pitch
    const pitch=parseFloat(  ((Cesium.Math.PI_OVER_TWO-Cesium.Math.acosClamped(direction.z))*180/Math.PI).toFixed(2));
    return{ pitchDegrees : pitch, headingDegrees: heading, altDegrees : pitch, elevDegrees : pitch, azimuthDegrees : heading};
}

Or, once you have defined a generic polyline:
var moonLine = viewer.entities.add({
    polyline: {
        positions: [],
        arcType: Cesium.ArcType.NONE,
        width: 2,
        material: Cesium.Color.GRAY
    }
});

you can make it go from observer to moon:
moonLine.polyline.positions = [startPos, moonPos];

(you can define startPos by  tartPos = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(lon, lat, height); )
Or you can point camera to the moon:
function orientOnMoon() {  
  var startPos = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(lon, lat, height);
  var moonPos = getMoonSunPos().moon;
  var temp = getHeading(startPos, moonPos);  
 
  viewer.scene.camera.flyTo({  
    destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromRadians(
      viewer.camera.positionCartographic.longitude, 
      viewer.camera.positionCartographic.latitude, 
      viewer.camera.positionCartographic.height+300),
    orientation: {   
      heading: temp.azimuthDegrees * Math.PI / 180,  
      pitch: -Math.PI / 2,  
      roll: 0  
    },  
    complete: function() {  
     // console.log("Fatto"); 
    }  
  });   
}  
  

If Moon looks too tiny, zoom on it by reducing Field Of View:
viewer3D.camera.frustum.fov = Cesium.Math.toRadians(degreesFOV);

Example code: sandcastle
